# Import sun class in Java-Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, sun

I'm tring to:

```
import sun.security.provider.SecureRandom;
```

And Eclipse is suggesting me to Search repositories for 'sun.security.provider'. It can see only the java.security.SecureRandom...

```
Access restriction: The type 'SecureRandom' is not API (restriction on required library '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar')
```

My BuildPath has the JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]

What can I check?

Comment: Content of `sun` package tends to change between Java versions so we are discouraged from using it your apps. Maybe instead use `java.security.SecureRandom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries in Eclipse have Access rules, so you cannot use every class (although they are present). These rules include the java.*, javax.* and the org.* packages (screenshot below).

When you change the library to use a specified JRE/JDK there are no access rules (second screenshot).
You can change them by selecting the library and pressing the "Edit..."-button on the right side. In the new window you choose "Alternate JRE" (third screenshot).

But what [Pshemo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334767/import-sun-class-in-java-eclipse#comment43126544_27334767) is correct, too, you should not use these libraries.

JRE with Access rules:
[image: Eclipse BuildPath]

JRE without Access rules:
[image: Eclipse BuildPath]

Dialog:
[image: Eclipse BuildPath]